# Sending Raspberry Pi data to a remote server

Tags: python, http, server, raspberry-pi3

I am storing some data in my Raspberry Pi database after validating it. I am using python. Now, I also want to send this data to a remote server. Please suggest a good method for the same.

Comment: take a look here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39348&p=324600

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming you are able to access your web resource(URI) through r-pi by connecting it to INTERNET or respected network, here am
>   posting simple example using which you can GET/POST parameters to your
>   remote webservice using request module in python which is by fa the
>   simplest way of achieving this using python specially on r-pi.

*The following sample assumes you are using HTTP POST to receive data at server side. You can also make use of HTTP GET method instead of POST.*

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://your-webservice-url", data={'param1': 'value1','param2': 'value2'})
if r.status_code == 200:
    //your code here to handle web response             
else:
    print r.text // in case of something went wrong!!
```

As, seen from above example code

> data={'param1': 'value1','param2': 'value2'}

represents parameters that could be passed to the web service you can send any no. of key/value pair here, in the form of 'param1': 'value1','param2': 'value2' ,etc.

Hope this works!